Callback Return None removes gridlines
In chart.js line chart, I place a vertical grid line in only every 720 ticks, which works fine.
then I add a number on the x axis using callback and it removes my nice gridlines.
this is also explained on the website
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats
There are 24 times 60 times 15 values in the array. I want a grid line every 60 time 15 values, labelled 0 to -23 from right to left. The array is updated every 5 seconds with a new value where the last one is removed.
the graph show the values of the last 24 hours.
Thank you.
Geert
        x: {
      beginAtZero: false, // X-axis should not start from 0
      grid: {
        display: true, // Ensure gridlines are displayed
        // drawTicks: false, // Disable tick-based control of gridlines
        color: function(context) {
          // Use context.index to control gridline color every hour
          if (context.index % 720 === 0) {
            return 'rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.2)'; // Hourly gridline color
          }
          // return 'transparent'; // Hide non-hourly gridlines
        }
      }, //grid x
      ticks: {
        display: true, // Show tick labels
        callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
          // Show a label every hour (720 indices)
          if (index % 720 === 0) {
            return  -24 + index / 720; // Calculate hour number
          }
          return ; 
        }
      } //ticks

I have been trying to make this work. only if I move the return of the if statement out side the if statement the grid line show, but only for 6 indexes. this seems not the right way and it doesnt work with the zooming.
Maybe someone know this problem an how to solve it?

Your code does work, see fiddle, except 24 * 60 * 15 is equal to 720 * 30, so there will be 30 ticks from -24 to +6. Also, for the grid lines to show, you have to set the same color for all cases; there will not be 24 * 60 * 15 grid lines, but only 30 - those that were already selected by the ticks callback (by returning a value, those for which no value was returned were already discarded).

yes so the return 'transparent' is not needed. thank you.

I solved it by disabling autoskip and returning an empty string in the if statement in the callback function.
    x: {
      beginAtZero: false, // X-axis should not start from 0
      grid: {
        display: true, // Ensure gridlines are displayed
        // drawTicks: false, // Disable tick-based control of gridlines
        color: function(context) {
          // Use context.index to control gridline color every hour
          if (context.index % 720 === 0) {
            return 'rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.2)'; // Hourly gridline color
          }
          // return 'transparent'; // Hide non-hourly gridlines
        }
      }, //grid x
      ticks: {
        display: true, // Show tick labels
        autoSkip: false,
             
        callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
          // Show a label every hour (720 indices)
          if (index % 1440 === 0) { // i used 1440 in stead of 720 to get less labels
            return  -24 + index / 720; // Calculate hour number
          }
          return '';
        }
      } //ticks

    }  //x

